# index was out of range. must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection. in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my application it has two datagridviews named datagridview1 and datagridview2 and I have the selectionChanged event in datagridview1 that captures the data that is selected in it so that the content of datagridview2 is also changed based on what the product name of the selected row in datagridview1 is. I don't know why I have an index that is out of range because I have checked that I have at least 1 row and 2 columns in datagridview1.
I am using DataView RowFilter function.

**Here is my code:**

```
private void datagridview1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    view_1.RowFilter = "product_name = '" + datagridview1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() +"'";
}
```

Comment: Missing a closing single quote at the end of the line?

Comment: @Steve, I'm sorry I forgot to copy. Edited Thanks!

Comment: If you gave us the stack trace we could help.

Comment: index provided to SelectedRows is required?

Comment: @ofstream, sorry I'm a newbie in programming in visual studio, if you don't mind me asking what is a stack trace?

Comment: @user2083771 Stack trace is that text that comes up with an error that shows where the error happened, exactly. Usually something like `SomeException at MyClass.Foo Line 42 at MyClass.Start at Program.Main` or something in that manner.

Comment: @user2083771 Sorry for not answering earlier. What you need to do is go to that method, wrap it in a try block (like try { //stuff }) and then after that put something like this: catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace); }. In the message box a bunch of text will pop up, could you please give us that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SelectionChanged event should fire when you unselect rows as well, so the SelectedRows should be empty and therefore you cannot index into it at all.

You should first check if it's `Length` is greater than zero, and only if it is, continue with the function.

Also, since I see you only handle a single selected row, I suggest you make sure you don't allow multi-row-selection on the `DataGridView` control (unless needed for something else, such as delete or whatever).

Comment: Okay...but I have a question how can I get the length? I mean what is the syntax of getting the length of the selected rows?

Comment: That's the easy part: `datagridview1.SelectedRows.Count`

Answer (score 0):

Like Yorye Nathan said "You should first check if it's Length is greater than zero, and only if it is, continue with the function."

```
private void datagridview1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
               view_1.RowFilter = "product_name = '" + datagridview1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() +"'";
            }

        }
```

Comment: No need to create an extra answer for yourself if one helped you. Others that will come across the same problem and get here will go through the same process and you did, and work it out. The expected thing to do is to mark the answer as accepted, so others will know which one help the OP so they can focus on it when they do need help with the same issue. It's also supposed to give the community some fake sense of motivation ;P

Comment: @YoryeNathan Okay, one last question Sir how will I disable the multi-row-selection on the DataGridView?

Comment: It's one of the properties you can set to it on design mode. `MultiSelect` set to `false` will limit to 1 selection at any given moment, and `SelectionMode` set to `FullRowSelect` will make the selection row-wise and not cell-wise (thought you'd might want that one too).